# Prove that $(a_n)$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

In the euclidean metric space $\mathbb{R}$, the sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n:=n$ is divergent.

Suppose $(a_n)$ is convergent. Then $\exists l \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $(a_n) \to l$. This means that given $\varepsilon >0$, we can find a natural number $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-l|<\varepsilon$ for every $n \ge N$.

Let $a_n=n$. Then $|n-l|<\varepsilon$.

Because $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varepsilon>0$, then $|n-l|<\varepsilon \iff -\varepsilon<n-l<\varepsilon \iff l-\varepsilon<n<l+\varepsilon$.

However, this is impossible since $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n>N$ and $a_n \ne a_N$. Thus $(a_n)$ is not eventually constant, and hence eventually $n>l+e$.

Would it be correct to say here instead that $\forall (l+\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>(l+\varepsilon)$; and therefore, $(a_n)$ must be divergent?

Comment: "*Since $\forall N\in\Bbb N,~\exists n\in \Bbb N$ for which $n>N$ and $a_n\neq a_N$.  Thus $(a_n)$ is not eventually constant*"  The same can be said for the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ yet that sequence does converge.

Comment: Suppose there was such an $l$.  Then, letting $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ and supposing there was such an $N$, letting $n=\text{max}(\lceil l\rceil,N)+1$ we see that $n\geq N$ and $|n-l|>\epsilon$ proving that no limit $l$ could exist.

Comment: Alternatively you may use the following result: A montone sequence is convergent if and only if it is bounded.

Comment: @JMoravitz Is there any particular reason for letting $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$? But I see how that forces $|n-l|>\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Karam I chose $\frac{1}{2}$ because it is an easy number to think of which is greater than zero and less than $1$.  I wanted a number greater than zero since that is a requirement of $\epsilon$ and I wanted a number less than one since otherwise with $n=l+1$ you have $|n-l|=1$ which might not have been greater than $\epsilon$.  Since we were supposed to be able to find $N$ *regardless* which epsilon we picked, it is fine to prove it isn't possible to find such an $N$ for a particular $\epsilon$ of our choosing that helps make the proof easier to write.

Comment: Why couldn't you just say that since $a_{n+1} - a_{n} = 1$, there can't be an $n$ for which the value of the sequence starts being constant?

Comment: @tempate the sequence being constant or not is irrelevant.  Again, $\frac{1}{n}$ converges as a sequence yet is never constant.  You can however use that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\neq 0$ to show the sequence is not [cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) which does also prove the sequence cannot converge using the fact that the real numbers are [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space).  The OP began their attempt with an $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of convergence, so I opted to continue with that.

Answer (score 1):

> In the euclidean metric space $\,\mathbb{R}\,,\,$ the sequence $\,\big(a_n\big)_{\!n\in\mathbb N}\,$ where $\;a_n\!:=n\;$ is divergent.

**Here is a direct proof :**

For any $\,k>0\,,\,$ there exists $\;n_k=\lfloor k\rfloor+1\in\mathbb N\;$ such that

for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\;\land\;n>n_k\;$ it results that

$a_n=n>n_k=\lfloor k\rfloor+1>k\;.$

Consequently ,

for any $\,k>0\,,\,$ there exists $\;n_k\in\mathbb N\;$ such that , $\,$for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\;\land\;n>n_k\;,\;$ it results that $\;a_n>k\;.$

And, by definition, it means that the sequence $\,\big(a_n\big)_{\!n\in\mathbb N}\,$ is divergent .